# How Can I Program A Robot to make coffee For me when I wake up?

Tags: equipment, brewing-process

Would a Raspberry Pi work for this?
Or maybe one of those android robots?

I don't wake up at a certain time everyday its totally random, so I cant use a Timer I need a sensor that will sense if i'm awake.
Please email me if you think the same as me.

Comment: This guy on twitter @alhazmy13 has done it. I think he uses Arduino. Go ask him :).

Comment: Watch the animated short "The Wrong Trousers."  Maybe you can pick up some points from Wallace.  Or a younger sibling (aka slave) might be an alternative.

Comment: @onlyforthis -- Can you suggest a direct link? If so, please feel free to expand into an answer...

Comment: @Allen -- If this is a serious question, have you considered other non-robot options such as suggested in answers below?

Comment: @hoc_age https://twitter.com/alhazmy13  Here is the guy's account on twitter. I'm not sure if he has documented what he did. You can ask him personally and he might help. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can. Get, for example, a [PR2 robot](http://www.willowgarage.com/pages/pr2/overview) and program it accordingly. You can also use simpler robots, but in all cases, you will either end up with a ridiculous amount of cost, or with a very unreliable performance. Not mentioning the hours of programming time you will have to spend on the project.

You may be better off buying a coffee maker that you can control remotely, e.g., [via Wifi](http://newatlas.com/grind-brew-smarter-coffee/35981/). Use the app to start the coffee making process once you are awake, or program your phone to detect that and start it for you. In industrial settings, robots are almost never the answer for tasks you can do without (e.g., button pressing). This is not so much different.

(I am not affiliated with any of the producers of the products linked to in this post.)

Answer (score 1):

Robot: consisting of - a coffee maker you fill with water and coffee the night before, an outlet, wired to a switch by your bed. Wake up, flip switch, done.

Robot: consisting of - a pot of cold-brewed coffee or coffee concentrate (and a microwave if you want it hot).

Robot: consisting of - an alarm clock by your bed, and a normal automatic timer-operated coffee maker.